# Sync Sequelize Databases on Serverless app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, serverless-framework

I am using sequelize with MySQL on the Serverless offline app.

I am not sure how to sync all models on serverless start?

I am tried to do this

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import mysql2 from 'mysql2';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'root', '', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: mysql2,
    host: 'localhost',
});

const getSequelize = () => {
    sequelize.sync({ force: false })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`Database & tables synchronised!`)
        });

    return sequelize;
}

export default getSequelize();
```

This approach syncs models that are imported into controller, so the only way in this case to sync all models is to include all models in every controller.

This does not look like a good example.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sequelize.sync` only for development purposes. Use [sequelize migrations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html) for production.

There must be some way to run console command `db:migrate` in your environment. When you push all the migration code use that command to update your database to the last version.